# Scale SVG coordinate system without scaling element sizes

Tags: html, css, svg, transform

I have a bunch of circles in SVG.

I would like to zoom in 2x such that the distances between all the circles are 2x apart, but the stroke-thickness and radius remain the same.

(I use circles here as an easy example, but the same idea extends too all shapes. I would like the end points of lines to become 2x far apart but keep the line thickness the same.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect devil is in the detail, is it a dynamic zoom by the user, could you just translate the objects for example ? Maybe post up a fiddle of an example.